# Not really sure how to proceed further with this inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

> The question:

Prove that $4xyzw \leq x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4$ for any $x, y, z, w \in ℝ$.

I am sure there are various tricks that can be used to prove this inequality, however, I can't seem to think of them. Perhaps I'm overthinking it.

> What I have tried doing:

Tackling the inequality like so (breaking it down into two pieces and adding them back together):
$(x^4+y^4)\ge 2x^2y^2$ 
$(z^4+w^4)\ge 2z^2w^2$

$(x^4+y^4) + (z^4+w^4)\ge 2x^2y^2 + 2z^2w^2$.
 Well, this isn't really what I need.

I am quite lost, and would greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: note:  when $x=y=z=w,$ equality occurs

Comment: Wouldn't this only cover one specific case in our proof?

Comment: [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) applied to $x^4, y^4, z^4, w^4$

Comment: @Robert Could you please demonstrate? Thanks!

Comment: AM-GM for $n=4$ says if $s,t,u,v \ge 0$, $(stuv)^{1/4} \le (s+t+u+v)/4$.  Taking $s=x^4$, $t=y^4$, $u=z^4$,$v=w^4$ this becomes $|xyzw| \le (x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4)/4$.  Of course $xyzw \le |xyzw|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, $$2x^2y^2+2z^2w^2=2(xy-zw)^2+4xyzw\geq4xyzw.$$